# initialize SKNode with multiple SKSpriteNodes

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm building a game where the characters have health bars. I did some quick research and found that subclassing an SKNode and adding SKSpriteNode members for the character and the health bar respectively is a good approach. So currently I have this:

```
class GameCharacter: SKNode {

 let characterBody = SKSpriteNode()
 let characterHealthBar = SKSpriteNode()

}
```

however I'm not sure how to init this so that both the sprite nodes appear. Effectively what I want is the character body on top, and the health bar underneath it.

I know this is the init method for SKSpriteNode to initialize with a size and texture:

```
override init() {
 let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "CharacterStanding.png")
 super.init(texture: texture, color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: texture.size())
}
```

does SKNode have a similar init method? or is it sufficient to init the two SKSpriteNodes within the SKNode and then just make a new GameCharacter object in the game scene?

or I guess what I'm trying to ask is; how do I init this GameCharacter(SKNode) object and both character and health bar appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

heres a solution I found so far:

in the init method just do the following:

```
override init() {
 super.init()
 self.addChild(characterBody)
 characterHealthBar.position = 
     CGPoint(x: characterBody.position.x, y: characterBody.position.y - 45)
 self.addChild(characterHealthBar)
}
```

and this will init the node with the character and the health bar below him/her

Answer (score 1):

If you're having problems with z-index in sprite kit its generally caused by the optimisations the system make with `ignoresSiblingOrder = true`, you can handle this defining zPosition by hand in each node.

More information about [Drawing Order for a Node Tree](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Nodes/Nodes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH3-SW1)